# Tensorflow: How to connect a multi-dimensional tensor to different Dense layers and concatenate them to an output

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to connect a multi dimensional output of my transformer model in keras to separate Dense layers, which are then concatenated afterwards.

My transformer output tensor looks like this:

```
decoder_output # dims: [batchSize, numQuerys, embedDim]
```

I want to connect each of the 64 query outputs (`decoder_output[:, i, :]`) to a seperate Dense layer and finally concatenate them so that my final model output has the shape  `[batchSize, numQuerys]` .

I wanted to do it with a for loop, but that does not seem to work due to the graph construction. Any ideas how to achieve this are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: We can use the Keras functional API and the Lambda layer to apply a custom function to each slice of the decoder_output.

# please Use the Lambda layer to apply the function

     `dense_outputs = Lambda(lambda x: apply_dense(x))(input_layer)`

# Need to Concatenate the outputs

      `concatenated_output = Concatenate(axis=-1)(dense_outputs)`

# We can Create the final model
      `final_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=concatenated_output)`

Kindly follow this steps to separate dense layer and finally concatenated them to an output. let me know if you have any concerns.